# Php variables variables including text which are not wanted

Tags: php, variables

I have a problem with the following variables:

```
$ID = uniqid();    
mkdir("temp/" . $ID);
$target_dir = "temp/" ;
$target_file = $target_dir . "/" . $ID . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$target = basename($target_file,".docx");
$uploadOk = 1;
```

When I echo the $target variable it is including the $ID at the begining. I don't need it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you don't need it, why did you write `$target_dir . "/" . $ID . ...` ? Remove the `$ID` from that concatenation.

Comment: It is answered by Bogdan Kuštan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one `/` in line:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . "/" . $ID . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Should be:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . "/" . $ID . "/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're including content of the `$ID` variable into the content of the `$target_file` variable. What's so weird about that?